# Unable to pull kotlin jar as a dependency in another project

Tags: java, maven, kotlin

I am currently working on a project, where I have a Kotlin project[A]. The project has different utility classes as well as interfaces. I have another Kotlin project [B]. I have published the artifact for project A, and I have added project A as a dependency on the POM file for project B. Now, I want to implement the interfaces in project A in Project B. When I try to import, I am unable to find the package from project A. Also, I have added the .jar file of project A manually in project B. I am unable to import the interfaces. I can see the jar file for project A in the external dependencies.

Summary:

Kotlin project A with Interfaces published as an Artifact
Kotlin project B has a pom file, in which project A's dependency is added.

Problem: Unable to find the classes, interfaces of project A in project B.

Comment: can you share a trimmed down version of the POMs to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.esrx.services</groupId>
<artifactId>projectB </artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Project B</name>
<description>Generic desc</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.esrx</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.esrx.services</groupId>
        <artifactId>Project A</artifactId>
        <version>Project A Version</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As you can see above the project A has the interfaces, I am pulling them as a dependency and trying to implement them as concrete classes in project B.

This is the interface I have in Project A that I am trying to implement in project B

```
interface Transformer {
fun transform(
        fieldName2FieldNameMap: Map<String, String>,
        json: String): Map<String, Any?>
 }
```